# Saying “That’s the whole point”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage

I have seen three possible translations of *That’s the whole point*:

- Das ist es ja gerade.
- Das ist es doch eben.
- Genau darum geht es.

Is there any difference in the quality/context/tone of the three translations, or are they pretty much the same?

I like the third one the best for some reason, but I am also sure there are many other ways one can translate it.

Comment: Alternative: _das ist/war [der] Sinn/Zweck der Sache_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those three statements are not exactly the same. Especially the meaning of the third is a little bit diffrent.

> Das ist es ja gerade.
>
> Das ist es doch eben.

Those two are more like a **negating** of what the other said “But that is the whole point.” *(even if I think the second one sounds false, some kind of bumpy, to me as a native Swiss German speaker.*

> Genau darum geht es.

That one is more **accepting** of what the other said. “Yeah, that exactly is the whole point.”

Now it depends on the context, which one to choose.

Comment: Das ist genau der Punkt. :)

Comment: I agree with you about the atmosphere being transferred by the translations of *That's the whole point*. Nevertheless, I'd like to suggest that the  idiomatic equivalent in german is *Das ist der springende Punkt*. The other suggestions aren't necessarily wrong, but *Das ist der springende Punkt* might be more idiomatic.